# Query SharePoint XML webservice in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, sharepoint, oracle12c

Is there a way to query a SharePoint list (e.g. http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers) from Oracle, such that it would return results that could be combined with data from an Oracle table?

This Youtube video describes a process that first table-izes the data:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hqtSHx1owo.  I'd like to be able to generate the same results, but without having to create a table first.

** edit **

Sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <id>http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers</id>
    <title type="text">Customers</title>
    <updated>2017-05-13T12:50:16Z</updated>
    <link href="Customers" rel="self" title="Customers"/>
    <entry>
        <id>http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers('ALFKI')</id>
        <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="NorthwindModel.Customer"/>
        <link href="Customers('ALFKI')" rel="edit" title="Customer"/>
        <link href="Customers('ALFKI')/Orders" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Orders" title="Orders" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"/>
        <link href="Customers('ALFKI')/CustomerDemographics" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CustomerDemographics" title="CustomerDemographics" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"/>
        <title/>
        <updated>2017-05-13T12:50:16Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name/>
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:CustomerID>ALFKI</d:CustomerID>
                <d:CompanyName>Alfreds Futterkiste</d:CompanyName>
                <d:ContactName>Maria Anders</d:ContactName>
                <d:ContactTitle>Sales Representative</d:ContactTitle>
                <d:Address>Obere Str. 57</d:Address>
                <d:City>Berlin</d:City>
                <d:Region m:null="true"/>
                <d:PostalCode>12209</d:PostalCode>
                <d:Country>Germany</d:Country>
                <d:Phone>030-0074321</d:Phone>
                <d:Fax>030-0076545</d:Fax>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <link href="http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$skiptoken='ERNSH'" rel="next"/>
</feed>
```

Comment: link does not work.  Please show sample data

Comment: Take a look at the TABLE function - https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions#table_functions

Answer (score 0):

OK, this question got my interest.  Here is a stripped-down solution. I hardcoded the XML string.  You would need instead, to call UTL_HTTP to get the data, and pass it to the function.

```
CREATE TYPE test_row_Type AS OBJECT (
  id           VARCHAR2(100),
  customer_id  varchar2(50)

);

CREATE TYPE test_tab_type IS TABLE OF test_row_Type;


create table dummy ( id varchar2(100), other_stuff varchar2(100) );
insert into dummy values('http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers','HAVE A NICE DAY!');
commit;


create or replace function get_data_func( P_xml IN VARCHAR2 ) return test_tab_type
as
  l_tab  test_tab_type := test_tab_type();
  l_row test_row_Type;
  D_id varchar2(100);
  D_cust varchar2(100);
begin
    l_tab.extend;

with xml_data as
( select xmltype(p_xml) xml_result from dual )
select extractvalue(xml_result,'/feed/id','xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"'),
 extractvalue(xml_result,'/feed/entry/content/m:properties/d:CustomerID','xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
          xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata
          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"') 
into d_id, d_cust
from xml_data;

  l_row := test_row_type(d_id, d_cust);
  l_tab(l_tab.last) :=   l_row;
  RETURN l_tab;
end get_data_func;

select * from
table(get_data_func('<feed xml:base="http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <id>http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers</id>
       <entry>
        <updated>2017-05-13T12:50:16Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name/>
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:CustomerID>ALFKI</d:CustomerID>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>') ) t1,
dummy
where t1.id = dummy.id
```

[image]

Note that if P_XML parameter > 32K, it won't work.  If you need pass in bigger xml strings, then either change the type to a CLOB or XMLTYPE.